# C# How to get the lastest version of an item from each group?

Tags: c#

I have a collection of items and then group them up by itemID+version.
For an itemID with the same version value,  using the example of four instances with version A

1. If three of the “A”s have an empty “Status” while one is populated, take the one with the “Status”
2. If all four “A”s have a “Status”, take the one with the latest modified date (do not worry about the value of “Status”)
3. If two or three “A”s have a value in “Status” and the others are empty, take the populated one with the latest date modified
4. If all four “A”s have an empty “Status”, take the one with the latest modified date

Comment: Rather than _describing_ your code, can you _show_ your code?

Comment: This reduces to "Status trumps date". That is, look at the any with a status first and take the more recent, then look at any without status and take the most recent.

Answer (score 1):

The cases are all notionally the same if you rank "has a status" as eg 1 and "doesn't have a status" as 2 and then order by this preferentially over the date

As such it seems we could have:

```
items.GroupBy(
  i => (i.Id, i.Version), 
  (k, g) => g.OrderBy(i => i.Status.HasValue ? 1 : 2).ThenByDescending(i => i.DateModified).First()
);
```

This groups items on a tuple of id and version, then uses the overload of group by that processes it's own groupings after it's made them. The items in the group are sorted first by whether status has a value (and any status of any value takes priority over any non status item) then the modified date is used to split any ties

This form of GroupBy is essentially

```
items.GroupBy(i => (i.Id, i.Version))
  .Select(g => 
    g.OrderBy(i => i.Status.HasValue ? 1 : 2)
      .ThenByDescending(i => i.DateModified)
      .First() 
  );
```

which you may prefer

Comment: ooo i like this better than mine

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Linq` statements.  Use `Min` if you want the earliest date.  I didn't know what you mean by the status is "Empty" so the code below is assuming that status is a `string` and "Empty" in this case means that the `string` `IsNullOrWhiteSpace`.

```
var itemsWithStatus = items.Where(item => string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(item.Status));
if (itemsWithStatus.Any())
{
    return itemsWithStatus.Max(item => item.Date);
}
    return items.Max(item => item.Date);
```